# Get data from remote sql server in a .NET web service

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, web-services

I have created a simple web service in visual studio 2015 with C#. I have set up an sql server database with a table and i want to simply return any value from that table.

By searching i haven't found a very explanatory tutorial.

Should i add a server connection in VS and then use linq or use SqlConnection?

I also included an ADO Entity data model in the project but i don't know how to use it in the webMethod.

Does any good tutorial exist about all options that i have to connect to the db and provide some examples, too?

Comment: Use SqlConnection and SqlCommand or SqlDataAdapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's a web application I suggest saving the connection string into web.config.
Example:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="ConnStringNameHere" connectionString="Data Source=IPadress;Initial Catalog=databaseName;Integrated Security=False;User ID=name;Password=pass" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

You just have to add the user in SQL Server with the appropriate permissions.
That way you can have a couple of connection strings, each for a user type with specific permissions (some can only read, some can write, etc.)
You make a connection to the database with this simple code:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connStringName"].ConnectionString))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM user WHERE userName = username", connection))
{
connection.Open();
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if (reader.HasRows)
{
  while (reader.Read())
  {
   string id = (string)reader["Id"].ToString();
   //work here
  }
}
connection.Close();
}
```

And a useful link: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/837599/Using-Csharp-to-connect-to-and-query-from-a-SQL-da